# Comparing slices of binary data in python

Tags: python, performance, binary

Say I have a file in hexadecimal and I need to search for repeating sets of bytes in it. What would be the best way to do this in python?

Right now what I'm doing is treating everything as a string with the re module, which is extremely slow and not the right way to do it. I just can't figure out how to slice up and compare binary data.

```
for i in range(int(len(data))):
    string = data[i:i+16]
    pattern = re.compile(string)
    m = pattern.findall(data)
    count += 1
    if len(m) > 1:
        k = [str(i), str(len(m))]
        t = ":".join(k)
        output_file.write(' {}'.format(t))
    else:
        continue
```

Just to make sure there's no confusion, `data` here is just a big string of hex data from `open('pathtofile/file', 'r')`

Comment: if it is string then maybe use standard string methods like `one_string.count(sub_string)`

Comment: BTW: you can also try to reduce size of compared data - for example calculate hashes for all substrings and then compare hashes.

Comment: @furas that works, but is it really the "right way" to do it? I feel like if you're given data, you should work with the raw bytes if possible.

Comment: did you try to use `count()` with bytes ? It should work too.

Comment: BTW: you can write in one line `output_file.write(' {}:{}'.format(i, len(m)))`

Comment: BTW: wikipedia [Search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithm)